Issues exporting .glb/.gltf with two or more actions in the NLA
Hello blender pros!
Blender noob here - having some issues with turning a rigged animation into .glb/.glft. Also, I'm not quite nailing the textures just yet (the gltf is more shiny than the glb so I have to figure that out too).
The main issue is that I have 276 frames worth of keyframe animation that I would like to split into two animation takes so these can be toggled on/off by the webdeveloper. It works well to export this as a single animation, but when I try to turn the keyframe animation into "push down to action" and then split the track in the NLA where I would like to have the second take start and rename the parts (on this single track) things get weird.
Upon export with keyframe sequence converter into an action, the whole object turns 90 degrees both in the file and in the scene (+Y up is ticked - and un-ticking it doesn't change anything). But when I undo the "push down to action" and just have a track of keyframes - this works again but I only have a single animation take.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get this super messy animation to a single file with 2x animation takes?
To just see if I got the same result with a super simple scene, I made a 4x keyframe animation of a cube moving around with the same approach I meantioned above, just turning it to an action, splitting the track - and there is no animation data saved in the glb for this cube. How do I go about making these two separate takes in a single glb? Exporting it with the keyframes being just keyframes worked though, not through NLA.
Thank you, and any help is much appreciated
